# Docker service update downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

I have an AWS EC2 with docker service.
The service has just 1 container, and when I update the container (changing image), I have a downtime (about 1 minute).

This is my docker service create code:

```
docker service create \
    --name service-$IMAGE_NAME \
    --publish 80:80 \
    --env ENVIRONMENT=$(cat /etc/service_environment) \
    --env-file=/etc/.env \
    --replicas=1 \
    --update-failure-action rollback \
    --update-order start-first \
    $ECR_IMAGE
```

Here update code:

```
#pull image from private ECR repository
docker pull $IMAGE

docker service update \
--force \
--image $IMAGE:latest \
--update-failure-action rollback \
--update-order start-first \
service-$IMAGE_NAME
```

Why this happen? What's wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Changing image means you are stopping existing docker instance, and start a new one. That's why it will be down for a while, in your case, 1 minute. It's the time for the docker instance to restart. You can make this seamless using 2 ec2 instance and load balancer. You update 1 instance and repointing the traffic to other instance, and then update the other one after the instance you've update is successful.

Comment: when I run docker service update, it starts one container, and after 1m , it starts a new container again. The first one doesn't works, but the second works... it's strange.
In my case, I'm using --update-order start-first so it should switch to the new container only when it is up. 
I think it is doing so, but the first created container doesn't works, and I don't know why :-/

Comment: I've found an error on pipeline. It was deploy twice with different dockerfile